# Absolutely positioned pseudo element in foreignObject rendering at the wrong location

Tags: css, safari

I have a `foreignObject` inside an SVG, and I want to show a vertical line extruding from that element upwards. The following example ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q9a8f0kg/)) reproduces this (your browser should be wide enough, I didn't care for scrolling here):

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.node-container {
  overflow: visible;
}

.node {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 1, 0.2);
}

.node:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  border: 1px solid red;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 500px;
  bottom: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg width="100%" height="100%">
    <g transform="translate(300 100)">
      <g>
        <foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="50px" height="50px" class="node-container">
          <div class="node"></div>
        </foreignObject>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

In Chrome and FireFox, this looks as expected:

[image]

But in Safari, the line gets rendered elsewhere:

[image]

The funny thing, however, is that Safari does appear to know where it *should* be, because inspecting the pseudo element gives this:

[image]

I'm aware that cross-browser, CSS works in very limited capacities inside `foreignObject`s (and painfully so). I am wondering, however, if this behavior has a good explanation as I cannot rule out that what I'm doing is just "odd". Any links to bug reports, if applicable, would be appreciated as answers as well.